# Removing files older then 1 month, but leave files created at the 1st day of the month

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I'm trying to remove some archive files from a folder on a CentOS fileserver with a cronjob. The requirements:

1. Remove files of the last month
2. The .tgz-file of the first day of the month should be left intact.

I know I can remove files older then x days with:

```
find /path -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

However, that won't leave alone the archive created at the first day of the month. The internet doesn't seem to be providing an answer (yet).

Comment: Is your files named after the date, as in e.g. `log-2013-02-27.tgz` and such? In that case you could run `touch *-01.tgz` before the `find` command. All files from the first of each month should be updated to the current timestamp and thus not matched.

Comment: Won't using `+29` instead of `+30` do?

Comment: How about `find /path -mtime +30 ! -name log-2013-02-01.tgz -exec rm {} \;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First a note

On unix file systems you have no information about the creation time of a file.
What is often call *ctime* is the *status change time* of a file.
This may be change by file renaming or permission changes.

See this [link](http://www.computer42.org/xwiki-static/exported/DevNotes/xwiki.DevNotes.LinuxTimeStamp.html) for more informations.

So be warned that the following solution may be failing.

#### Solution with the help of `awk`

`find` has no operator for selecting a special date. So the trick is
to create an output with the day of month and the file name and using
a separator which is not part of the filenames.
I assume that `#` is such a possible separator char.

```
 find . -mtime +30 -printf "%Cd#%p\n"
```

In a 2nd step you can filter out the unwanted files.

```
 find . -mtime +30 -printf '%Cd#%p\n' |awk -F'#' '$1 !~ /^01/{print $2;}'
```

#### Solution with the help of `grep` and `cut`

Doing the same trick as above.

```
 find . -mtime +30 -printf '%Cd#%p\n' |grep -v '^01' |cut -d '#' -f 2
```